# How to search for a message in a file without repeating already searched lines in Robot Framework

Tags: robotframework

I would like to look for a particular message in a constantly updating file. I used *Wait Until Keyword Succeeds* with my own keyword to search the file and it works fine.

```
*** Test Cases ***
${lineCount}    MyKeywordToGetLineCountToStartSearch    ${filename}
Wait Until Keyword Succeeds    10s    2s    KeywordToLookForTheMessage    ${filename}    ${linecount}    ${message}

*** Keywords ***
KeywordToLookForTheMessage
[Arguments]    ${filename}    ${linecount}    ${message}
Run    tail -n +${linecount} ${filename} > ${locationdir}/${newfile}
${filecontent}    Get File    ${locationdir}/${newfile}
@{lines}    Split To Lines    ${filecontent}
${result_list}    Create List
: FOR    ${line}    IN    @{lines}
    \    ${state}    ${msg}    Run Keyword And Ignore Error    Should Contain    ${line}    ${message}
    \    Run Keyword If    '${state}' == 'PASS'    Append To List    ${result_list}    ${line}
Should not be empty    ${result_list}
```

Now what I'm missing is ,

- With each iteration I need the line count to be updated so that I don't look through the same lines again .
- While doing that, I would also want to retain the original line count value for further in the testcase.

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This kind of complex logic should be implemented in test library using Python, not trying to use lower level keywords provided by existing libraries.